# convert JSON from string with array value included

Tags: php

As the following string, use json_decode to convert it into an array. However, after conversion, the value of `TbManager:userAccesses[]` is still a string.

`TbManager:userAccesses[]` could be converted to array by calling json_decode again for it, `json_decode($json['TbManager:userAccesses[]']`), but how to convert it in the first json_decode call?

```
$json = '{
"TbUser:username":"admin",
"TbManager:userAccesses[]":"[\"1\",\"8\"]"
}'

// converted to JSON with 'TbManager:userAccesses[]':string
// how to conver TbManager:userAccesses[] as array type
$json = json_decode($json)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"TbManager:userAccesses[]":"[\"1\",\"8\"]"
```

Over there  this is a single value `"[\"1\",\"8\"]"` it is not an array according to JSON syntax, hence the output you see.

Array would be when the value is like

```
$json = '{
"TbUser:username":"admin",
"TbManager:userAccesses":[1,8]
}';
```

Comment: the output of TbManager:userAccesses[] after json_decode is ["1", "8"], and also, if 1, 8 are in string, how to declare TbManager:userAccesses[] in string? by using single quote?

Comment: I see, it is because of the quotation of `[ ]`, since there is an quotation the processor use it as a string

Answer (score 1):

It's because your JSON data have bad format. The right format of your JSON data:

```
{"TbUser:username":"admin","TbManager:userAccesses[]":[1,8]}
```

in your code it will be:

```
$json = '{
"TbUser:username":"admin",
"TbManager:userAccesses[]":[1,8]
}';
```

And then:

```
var_dump($json);
```

will output:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["TbUser:username"] => string(5) "admin"
  ["TbManager:userAccesses[]"] => array(2) {
    [0] => int(1)
    [1] => int(8)
  }
}
```

Comment: *Bad* or *not fit for the purpose* Format?

Comment: __not fit for the purpose__ sounds better :/

Answer (score 1):

Your $json should look like

```
{"TbUser:username":"admin","TbManager:userAccesses[]":[1,8]}"
```

In this case 'TbManager:userAccesses[]' will be array after json_decode

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, it's not a valid json string, but if that's what you get, here's a snippet that would convert those values to array:

```
$json = '{
    "TbUser:username":"admin",
    "TbManager:userAccesses[]":"[\"1\",\"8\"]"
}';

$json = json_decode($json);

array_walk_recursive($json, function (&$item, $key)
{
    if (substr($key, -2) == '[]') {
        $item = json_decode($item);  
    }
});

print_r($json);
```